# Extjs: Resize panel in Viewport when browser window is resizes

Tags: javascript, extjs, viewport

I have a panel:

```
var myPanel = Ext.form.Panel({   width : 400,   height : '50%', ... } // for center panel on screen
items : [{
    xtype : 'component',
    html : <add image>
```

This panel is inside Viewport:

```
    Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout : 'ux.center',
        items : [form]
    });
```

Problem: When I resize the browser window, the panel becomes a cropped height

How can I do so that the height varied as in rubber layout ?

Answer (score 0):

Use 'vbox' layout with proper layoutConfig (pack: center, align: center) for your viewport and the resize should be done correctly.

Comment: layout: 'vbox',
layoutConfig : {pack: center, align: center}

After the changes Viewport align left